# cannot get out of while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Very basic question. Want to start using while loops in my code. Made a test data set that looks like this:

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is line four
This is line five
```

I want to print:

```
This is line two
This is line three
```

I know alternative ways of writing this code, but I SPECIFICALLY want to write this code using a while loop to practise how it works.

The code I have so far is:

```
import sys
fileopen = open(sys.argv[1])
print_line = False
for line in fileopen:
    if "two" in line:
        print_line = True
        while print_line:
            print line
        if "four" in line:
            break
```

This just continuously prints "This is line two". 
Can someone show me how to edit this code so that, using the while loop, the output is:

```
This is line two 
This is line three
```

Thanks

Comment: You're stuck in the while loop because you never change `print_line` back to false. Since it is always true, it will always stay in that loop. I honestly cannot imagine why you would ever want to do this with a while loop, though.

Comment: Your `if` condition is **outside the `while` loop**.

Comment: If you want to use a `while` loop somewhere, try replacing the `for` loop, not the `if` statement.

Comment: _"but I SPECIFICALLY want to write this code using a while loop to practise how it works."_ It may be counterproductive to try to solve a problem using a tool not particularly suited for the task. You might as well say "I want to build a birdhouse using this garden hose because I want to practice how it works". Garden hoses are indeed useful, but not for woodworking.

Comment: @Kevin Your example is ridiculous. It's perfectly natural to try to experiment with other ways of doing loops. It'll help him understand when a for loop is most appropriate.

Comment: @CrazyCasta That's true for if the OP was using a `while` loop in place of a `for` loop, but here it looks like they're using it in place of an `if` statement.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Ok, but if you read the question, the questioner says: "Want to start using while loops in my code." and "but I SPECIFICALLY want to write this code using a while loop to practise how it works." It would seem more productive to offer a good example of how the questioner could use a while loop. I agree that perhaps the questioner is a bit confused as to what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

One way to "use a while loop" would be like so:

```
import sys
fileopen = open(sys.argv[1])
print_line = False
try:
    while True:
        line = fileopen.next()
        if "two" in line:
            while True:
                print line
                line = fileopen.next()
                if "four" in line:
                    break
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: @user1288515, The `for` will already loop over every line in the file, so to learn about `while`, you need to replace it like @CrazyCasta has done here.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
while print_line:
            print line
```

to:

```
if print_line:
            print line
```

As you can see, there is nothing to change `print_line` to `False` so it's effectively the same as `while True`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you for versions of Python >= 2.7

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        if "two" in  line or "four" in line:
            print line,
        line = file.readline()
```